# Running the Project Continuously

Tags: python, operating-system

I have 2 pyhton .py files and I want these files to run for 24 hours.I created a function for a file as below. But it gives warning as 'ERROR: The process "mobil-2.py" not found.'

> I have another py file named mobil-3 and I want to do the same thing after 1800 seconds. How can I provide this operation for these two files?

> I want it to run these two files every 20 minutes for 24 hours.

Your help is very valuable to me. Thank you.

```
def func1():
  while True:
    os.system("mobil-2.py")

def func2():
  while True:
    time.sleep(1200)
    os.system('taskkill /IM "mobil-2.py" ')

def thread():
  th1 = threading.Thread(target = func1)
  th1.start()

  th2 = threading.Thread(target = func2)
  th2.start()

thread()
```

Comment: the process is python, not the name of the scrpt.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your CWD is not in the Directory you expect it to be.

> ERROR: The process "mobile-de-2.py" not found.

For example if you open a Project in VSCode it defaults its CWD to the Parent Directory of the Project when it Debugs/Runs.
That is probably why "mobile-de-2.py" can't be found because it isn't in the Directory your Program is searching in.

But I have no experience with running Files for a defined amount of Time, so I sadly can't help you with that.

Comment: Do i need to install something for cwd, sorry i didn't understand.

Comment: cwd = os.getcwd() , Or should I add a command?

Comment: CWD as in Current Working Directory. Your Program Searches for "mobile-de-2.py" in the Current Working Directory. So if the File isn't present in that Location it can't find it.

Comment: 'mobil-2.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file, I'm getting the warning now.